# Error: response status is 400 while trying to fill database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my web api I was trying to fill database with some object, here is method:

```
 try
    {
        var ac = await _dataContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Contacts.Any(y => y.Email == email));
        
        var newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.FirstName = firstName;
        newContact.SecondName = secondName;
        newContact.Email = email;
        ac.Result.Contacts.Add(newContact);
    
        _dataContext.Contacts.Add(newContact);
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e);
    }
```

After executing this with data, I got 400 error responce.
Database strucutre:

```
public class Account
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }


}public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Upd: 400 responce problem was with catch block. After fixing that, I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line  `ac.Result.Contacts.Add(newContact);`

Comment: Please share your exception detail to understand the real problem

Comment: Thank you for the responce. Here is all api gives:
Code Details
400
Undocumented
Error: response status is 400

Response headers
 content-length: 0 
 date: Tue,13 Sep 2022 11:06:19 GMT 
 server: Kestrel

Comment: In your `catch (Exception e)` what exception do you get?

Comment: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr' instances are not supported. Path: $.TargetSite.MethodHandle.Value.

Answer (score 0):

missing the `await` here as youre using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` not `FirstOrDefault`

```
var ac = await _dataContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Contacts.Any(y => y.Email == email));
```

Comment: Thank you for repsonce, yes, changed that. But the problem with  
Error: response status is 400 is still here.

Comment: ah ok. Put a breakpoint in the catch `exception` and add the error message in your answer and someone might be able to help